# Linear Algebra, Vector Space: how to find intersection of two subspaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

$${ W = Sp\{{(1,3,4),(2,5,1)\}}\\ U = Sp\{{(1,1,2),(2,2,1)}} \}$$
**Find a span** $$U \cap W$$

First time using Math latex, pretty hard.

Comment: just $$U{\bigcap}W$$ Which I believe is the same as $$Sp(U{\bigcap}W)$$ Because U and W are Sub-Vector Spaces of $$R^3$$

Comment: I need to find a group that Spans $$U{\bigcap}W$$. can't be wat u said.

Comment: Hint: the vectors in U are linearly independent and so are those in W. So U and W represent planes in $R^3$ The vectors in U and W are not linear multiples of each other so the planes are not parallell. The intersection will be a line, i.e. the span of a single vector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is Sp(1, 1, -10).

Call the vectors a = (1,1,2); b = (2,2,1); c = (1, 3, 4); d = (2, 5, 1) then any vector in $U \bigcap W$ must be a linear combination of a and b, and at the same time a linear combination of c and d.

This gives you the following simultaneous equations:

$\alpha$(1,1,2) + $\beta$(2,2,1) = $\gamma$(1,3,4) + $\delta$(2,5,1). Solve them by the method of your choice to get a parametric equation for a line.

Comment: I've put $${α(1,1,2) + β(2,2,1) = γ(1,3,4) + δ(2,5,1)}$$ into $${α(1,1,2) + β(2,2,1) - γ(1,3,4) - δ(2,5,1) = 0}$$ and then I made a matrix, found the General solution to the matrix. and then checked with the Generael solution and according to W's span and U's span what's the intersection between U and W.

Comment: Good. This method is appropriate for vector spaces in general. You could for example find the intersection of a line an a plane by the same method (either a point, or the line itself) whereas cross products are only applicable to lines in 2D. I deleted some earlier comments on your question itself: you could tidy up your responses to them for the benifit of future readers.

Comment: Alright, thank you Tom.

Comment: Correction: should have said cross products only applicable in 3D not 2D.

Answer (score 11):

Let $U$ and $V$ be two sub spaces(in matrix form: columns as basis vectors). Let $z$ be a vector that lies in intersection of these two sub spaces. Then $\exists$ two coeff vectors $x,y$ such that 
\begin{align*}
z = Ux &= Vy \\
Ux &= Vy \\
U^T Ux &= U^T Vy \\
x &= (U^T U)^{-1} U^TVy \quad \text{ and similarly } \quad y = (V^T V)^{-1} V^TUx  \\ 
\text{Thus} \quad x &= (U^T U)^{-1} U^TV(V^T V)^{-1} V^TUx \\
x &= \hat{M}x, 
\end{align*}
where, $$\hat{M} =(U^T U)^{-1} U^TV(V^T V)^{-1} V^TU $$ 
We can see that $x$ is the Eigen vector of $\hat{M}$ corresponding to Eigen value $1$. Thus required basis is the set of independent vectors such that

$$\{Ux:\hat{M}x = x\}$$

In another way, let $\hat{M_1} = \Big(U(U^T U)^{-1} U^T \Big)  \Big(V(V^T V)^{-1} V^T \Big) = P_UP_V$. The required basis is the set of independent vectors such that

$$\{s:\hat{M_1}s = s\}$$

**Geometrically $P_U=U(U^T U)^{-1} U^T$ and $P_V =V(V^T V)^{-1} V^T $ are projection matrices onto the sub spaces $U$ and $V$ respectively. So we can see that the basis elements are those independent vectors, which remain unchanged after two  projections, corresponding to the given two sub spaces.**

Comment: If I only have U and V, is there a way to find also z in Matlab?

Comment: Yeah I guess. You can find the eigenvector of the Matrix $\hat{M_1}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. That is $z$

Comment: Why does $\hat M x = x$ imply that $x \in U \cap V$?  The other implication definitely holds, but that only tells you $U \cap V \subseteq \ker(\hat M - I)$.

Comment: $\hat{M_1}$ is product of two projection matrices, projection matrix always either decreases the vector length or keeps it constant. Thus any Eigen vector corresponding to Eigen value $1$, lies in both the subspaces.

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is years after the question, posting following for completeness. This is very similar to solution by Pavan Karjol.

Let $P_u$ and $P_v$ be two projection matrices onto the two sub-spaces spanned by the columns of $U$ and $V$. These are calculated as $P_u=U(U^T U)^{-1} U^T$ and $P_v =V(V^T V)^{-1} V^T.$

Let $z$ be a vector that lies in intersection of these two sub-spaces. Since  $z$ is on both sub-spaces, projecting it onto each subspace doesn't change the vector.

Therefore, $z = P_uz$ and $z = P_vz$.

Substituting one in the other gives $z = P_uP_vz$ therefore, $0 = (P_uP_v-I)z$ .

Meaning, $z$ is in the null space of $M=(P_uP_v - I)$. Perform the eigenvalue decomposition on $M$ and select the eigenvectors corresponding to zero or nearly zero eigenvalues and that forms an orthogonal basis for the intersection of given sub-spaces.

Comment: Clearly the null space of $M$ contains the intersection of the subspace spanned by the columns of $U$ and the subspace spanned by the columns of $V$, but could you say why they are equal?  Otherwise it might be that $\ker M$ is bigger than what is needed.

Comment: They should just be equal. Projection can only decrease or maintain the length of a vector if the linear space can be equipped with an inner product, and it maintains the length of a vector if and only if this vector is in the subspace corresponding to this projector. Now acting $P_v$ and $P_u$ successively to a vector in the null space of $M$, the length of this vector is maintained. This means that this vector must be in the intersection of the subspaces corresponding to $P_u$ and $P_v$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find the normal vector to each span. Then a vector is in the span if and only if the dot-product with the normal vector is $0$. The formula for the normal vector of a 2-d span in 3-d is the cross product of your two spanning vectors. So for your two spans, you get two normal vectors, say $u,v$, and then you want to solve the system $[u^T \,; \,  v^T]x = 0$ for $x$, which can be done with row elimination, or simply computing the cross product of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Well, I learn math on a different language (not English), which makes me hard to understand what you wrote. but to simplify, I understood that I need to take (1,3,4)(2,5,1) , (1,1,2)(2,2,1) put them on a Matrix, and then find two normal 3-d vectors and then wat?

Comment: You can get a normal to each subspace. Then you can get a cross product of the 2 normals. This gives a vector whose span is the intersection of the 2 subspaces.

Comment: @AmeetSharma That's an even better solution based on cross-products. I'll update.

Comment: I don't understand what you guys are saying because my Math english is bad. I'll get it if u can show an example though or direct me to a Linear Algebra website that you recommend that I can relate what you're saying to my language.

Comment: Have you studied cross product? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: Over-complicated ?