# Eigenvector test for stabilizability

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, stability-theory

Consider two following equivalent statements about the stabilizability:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = Ax + Bu \\
\end{equation}
where $x \in R^n$.

$1.$ The above system is stabilizable if and only if no eigenvector of $A^T$ with eigenvalue $Re\{\lambda\} \geq 0$ belongs to null($B^T$).

$2.$The above system is stabilizable if and only if $rank[A-\lambda I \;\;\; B] = n$ for $\lambda$ satisfying $Re\{\lambda\} \geq 0$.

Now consider the following $A$:

A = $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

$A^T$ has one eigenvalue which is $0$ with a multiplicity of $3$. The eigenvectors of $A^T$then are:

$v = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Now, if I choose $B^T$ as:

$B^T$ = $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

then $v$ is not in the null space of $B^T$ since $B^Tv \neq 0$. However if you check

$rank[A-\lambda I \;\;\; B] = rank[A \;\;\; B] = 2$

which should be $3$ since the statement $1$ is satisfied with the chosen $B$.

It seems there is a contradiction between the statements. Can you tell me what's wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix has repeated eigenvalues then any non-zero linear combination of their obtained eigenvectors would also satisfy as eigenvector for that eigenvalue. So in your case for example

$$
u = v_1 - v_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

also satisfies $A^\top u = \lambda\,u = 0$. However, $u$ does lie in the null space of $B^\top$.

---

So a more complete formulation for statement 1. would be:

A system is stabilizable if and only if for each eigenvalue $Re\{\lambda\}\geq0$ the intersect between the space spanned by the associated eigenvectors of $A^\top$ and null$(B^\top)$ is the origin.

Comment: Does that mean we should check whether all the linear combinations of eigenvectors do not belong to the null space of $B^T$ (not just the eigenvectors)? In this example you found a linear combination which violates the criterion.

Comment: I think if you have an eigenvalue with a multiplicity of $1$, then there will no problem.

Comment: @eet For finding the intersection you could for example look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/767882/76466). And yes, when the multiplicity is one, then the statement in your question and the modified version in my answer yield the same result.

Comment: @eet A way to solve the problem is to consider the expression $\alpha VB=0$ where $V$ is a basis of the eigenspace of the considered eigenvalue and $\alpha\ne 0$ is a row vector you want to find. If there is no such $\alpha\ne0$, then the mode is controllable, otherwise it is not. In the current case, this yields $\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, and equality holds with $\alpha=(1,-1)$.